# How do I have my WinForms app display a messagebox if a DateTimePicker's value is of today?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an Employee Management Windows Forms Application, and I need to have a MessageBox displayed if any textBox is left empty or the dateTimePicker's value is not changed, I have tried this:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || dateTimePicker1.Value == DateTime.Today)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill all of the text fields");
    return;
}
```

The MessageBox is displayed if a TextBox is left empty, but nothing happens if the date on the dateTimePicker is today's date

Comment: A DateTime is Date AND Time. DateTime.Today is a special value with time set to "00:00:00"

Comment: What's the actual value of `dateTimePicker1.Value`? Does it have a time part perhaps? In that case you should use `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Today`

Comment: Something is wrong with the way the DTP gets initialized, hard to see from here.  I'd guess it was done with DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.Today